# permission error on executing docker run

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run a docker run command as the root user. But I'm getting a error related to privileges.

Can anyone lead me in the right direction as to what I need to look into to resolve this? It's got a few people on my team stumped. We know it is definitely not the image because we can run the image on other boxes as well as locally without any issues.

thanks

```
docker run -it -p 8091:8081 999999999.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/999999999.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/node-xref-api-v2
panic: standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "permission denied" [recovered]
    panic: standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "permission denied"

goroutine 1 [running, locked to thread]:
panic(0x6f3000, 0xc42012ee70)
    /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1a1
github.com/urfave/cli.HandleAction.func1(0xc42007f748)
    /builddir/build/BUILD/docker-96d83a5ff6ec0eb9bb7b45192c3048fd3aef5e21/runc-81b254244390bc636b20c87c34a3d9e1a8645069/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/urfave/cli/app.go:478 +0x247
panic(0x6f3000, 0xc42012ee70)
    /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/panic.go:458 +0x243
github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer.(*LinuxFactory).StartInitialization.func1(0xc42007f198, 0xc42001e0b0, 0xc42007f238)
    /builddir/build/BUILD/docker-96d83a5ff6ec0eb9bb7b45192c3048fd3aef5e21/runc-81b254244390bc636b20c87c34a3d9e1a8645069/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer/factory_linux.go:259 +0x18f
github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer.(*LinuxFactory).StartInitialization(0xc42004e8c0, 0xaac9c0, 0xc42012ee70)
    /builddir/build/BUILD/docker-96d83a5ff6ec0eb9bb7b45192c3048fd3aef5e21/runc-81b254244390bc636b20c87c34a3d9e1a8645069/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer/factory_linux.go:277 +0x353
main.glob..func8(0xc420082780, 0x0, 0x0)
    /builddir/build/BUILD/docker-96d83a5ff6ec0eb9bb7b45192c3048fd3aef5e21/runc-81b254244390bc636b20c87c34a3d9e1a8645069/main_unix.go:26 +0x66
reflect.Value.call(0x6ddd80, 0x769ce8, 0x13, 0x73c1c9, 0x4, 0xc42007f708, 0x1, 0x1, 0x4d17a8, 0x732020, ...)
    /usr/lib/golang/src/reflect/value.go:434 +0x5c8
reflect.Value.Call(0x6ddd80, 0x769ce8, 0x13, 0xc42007f708, 0x1, 0x1, 0xac2700, 0xc42007f6e8, 0x4da786)
    /usr/lib/golang/src/reflect/value.go:302 +0xa4
github.com/urfave/cli.HandleAction(0x6ddd80, 0x769ce8, 0xc420082780, 0x0, 0x0)
    /builddir/build/BUILD/docker-96d83a5ff6ec0eb9bb7b45192c3048fd3aef5e21/runc-81b254244390bc636b20c87c34a3d9e1a8645069/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/urfave/cli/app.go:487 +0x1e0
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run(0x73c395, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x74d9d9, 0x51, 0x0, ...)
    /builddir/build/BUILD/docker-96d83a5ff6ec0eb9bb7b45192c3048fd3aef5e21/runc-81b254244390bc636b20c87c34a3d9e1a8645069/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/urfave/cli/command.go:191 +0xc3b
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).Run(0xc4200c6000, 0xc42000c120, 0x2, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0)
    /builddir/build/BUILD/docker-96d83a5ff6ec0eb9bb7b45192c3048fd3aef5e21/runc-81b254244390bc636b20c87c34a3d9e1a8645069/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/urfave/cli/app.go:240 +0x611
main.main()
    /builddir/build/BUILD/docker-96d83a5ff6ec0eb9bb7b45192c3048fd3aef5e21/runc-81b254244390bc636b20c87c34a3d9e1a8645069/main.go:137 +0xbd6
[root@ip-10-140-1-10 ~]# ^C
[root@ip-10-140-1-10 ~]# sudo docker run -it -p 8091:8081 231827969312.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/231827969312.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/node-xref-api-v2
panic: standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "permission denied" [recovered]
    panic: standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "permission denied"

goroutine 1 [running, locked to thread]:
panic(0x6f3000, 0xc42011ce70)
    /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1a1
github.com/urfave/cli.HandleAction.func1(0xc42007f748)
    /builddir/build/BUILD/docker-96d83a5ff6ec0eb9bb7b45192c3048fd3aef5e21/runc-81b254244390bc636b20c87c34a3d9e1a8645069/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/urfave/cli/app.go:478 +0x247
panic(0x6f3000, 0xc42011ce70)
    /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/panic.go:458 +0x243
github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer.(*LinuxFactory).StartInitialization.func1(0xc42007f198, 0xc42001e0c8, 0xc42007f238)
    /builddir/build/BUILD/docker-96d83a5ff6ec0eb9bb7b45192c3048fd3aef5e21/runc-81b254244390bc636b20c87c34a3d9e1a8645069/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer/factory_linux.go:259 +0x18f
github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer.(*LinuxFactory).StartInitialization(0xc42004f590, 0xaac9c0, 0xc42011ce70)
    /builddir/build/BUILD/docker-96d83a5ff6ec0eb9bb7b45192c3048fd3aef5e21/runc-81b254244390bc636b20c87c34a3d9e1a8645069/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer/factory_linux.go:277 +0x353
main.glob..func8(0xc420082a00, 0x0, 0x0)
    /builddir/build/BUILD/docker-96d83a5ff6ec0eb9bb7b45192c3048fd3aef5e21/runc-81b254244390bc636b20c87c34a3d9e1a8645069/main_unix.go:26 +0x66
reflect.Value.call(0x6ddd80, 0x769ce8, 0x13, 0x73c1c9, 0x4, 0xc42007f708, 0x1, 0x1, 0x4d17a8, 0x732020, ...)
    /usr/lib/golang/src/reflect/value.go:434 +0x5c8
reflect.Value.Call(0x6ddd80, 0x769ce8, 0x13, 0xc42007f708, 0x1, 0x1, 0xac2700, 0xc42007f6e8, 0x4da786)
    /usr/lib/golang/src/reflect/value.go:302 +0xa4
github.com/urfave/cli.HandleAction(0x6ddd80, 0x769ce8, 0xc420082a00, 0x0, 0x0)
    /builddir/build/BUILD/docker-96d83a5ff6ec0eb9bb7b45192c3048fd3aef5e21/runc-81b254244390bc636b20c87c34a3d9e1a8645069/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/urfave/cli/app.go:487 +0x1e0
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run(0x73c395, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x74d9d9, 0x51, 0x0, ...)
    /builddir/build/BUILD/docker-96d83a5ff6ec0eb9bb7b45192c3048fd3aef5e21/runc-81b254244390bc636b20c87c34a3d9e1a8645069/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/urfave/cli/command.go:191 +0xc3b
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).Run(0xc4200a0000, 0xc42000c120, 0x2, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0)
    /builddir/build/BUILD/docker-96d83a5ff6ec0eb9bb7b45192c3048fd3aef5e21/runc-81b254244390bc636b20c87c34a3d9e1a8645069/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/urfave/cli/app.go:240 +0x611
main.main()
    /builddir/build/BUILD/docker-96d83a5ff6ec0eb9bb7b45192c3048fd3aef5e21/runc-81b254244390bc636b20c87c34a3d9e1a8645069/main.go:137 +0xbd6
```

Comment: What Host OS ? Centos wit Selinux??

Comment: Hi. The host is CentOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. But I found the answer here

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1358819

I've fixed it temporarily by setting selinux to permissive mode

```
inside /etc/selinux/config

SELINUX=permissive
```

Answer (score 5):

On CentOS i got this error when my "/var" was mounted without execution permissions.

If possible try to remount it with exec permissions:

```
 mount /var/ -o remount,exec
```

and restart the Docker engine.

```
systemctl restart docker.service
```

If this works out, you have to adjust the fstabs, and remove `noexec`